# Can an Imp which is in another form (through Shapechanger) be invisible?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, polymorph

The [imp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/imp) has the Shapechanger trait:

> The imp can use its action to polymorph into a beast form that resembles a rat (speed 20 ft.), a raven (20 ft., fly 60 ft.), or a spider (20 ft., climb 20 ft.), or back into its true form. Its statistics are the same in each form, except for the speed changes noted. Any equipment it is wearing or carrying isn't transformed. It reverts to its true form if it dies.

As far as I can see, it only mentions that the statistics remain the same (aside from the speed).

**Can an imp still use its Invisibility action while shapechanged, or remain invisible while shapechanged?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The Invisibility action is part of its statistics

A monster's statistics are made up of everything in its stat block including its actions. You can find more information about it in the Monster Manual Introduction or [here in the DM's basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/monsters#MonsterStatistics); the subheadings under **Statistics** are:

1. Size
2. Type
3. Alignment
4. Armor Class
5. Speed
6. Ability Scores
7. Saving Throws
8. Skills
9. Senses
10. Languages
11. Challenge
12. Special Traits
13. Actions
14. Reactions
15. Limited Usage
16. Equipment

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. Then it's essencially the Imp in a different form with a different speed, retaining everything else.