# Can a shapechanged quasit use the blindsight of the bat form?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, polymorph, shapeshifting

The stat block of the [quasit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quasit) gives under the shapechanger trait:

> Its statistics are the same in each form, except for the speed changes noted.

So does a quasit will not have the traits of the "polymorphed" (earlier editions) form, like the *Blindsight* of a real [bat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bat) (with a fly speed of 30 feet), because the quasit itself has no *Blindsight* in its stat block, but *Darkvision 120 feet*?

Answer (score 8):

## The Quasit Does Not Gain Blindsight

You have already quoted the relevant text:

> Its statistics are the same in each form, except for the speed changes noted.

Knowing the definition of Statistics makes this clear. From page 6 of the Monster Manual:

> A monster's statistics, sometimes referred to as its **stat block**, provide the essential information you need to run the monster

In other words, according to the wording of the ability, nothing in the Quasit's stat block changes, except for the speed changes noted. The Quasit does not become a bat, it merely changes shape to look (and locomote) like one. The only change of note, aside from the speed changes, is that the Claw action is re-flavored as a Bite to better fit the new form. The Quasit still has full use of its Invisibility, and retains its ability scores, resistances, immunities, and all other features that make up the Quasit stat block. Refer to [this excellent answer by David Coffron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/128981/68718) (or pages 6-11 of the Monster Manual) for a full list of things that are considered a monster's Statistics.

Comment: This also results in the ability for turning invisible in all shapechanged forms too, as well as the imp's raven form for higher fly speed and devil's sight, isn't it?

Comment: Yes; the Quasit can use its _Invisibility_ action in its shapechanged forms, and an Imp familiar still has Devil's Sight in any of its forms.

Comment: Found this was answered under [Can an Imp which is in another form (through Shapechanger) be invisible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128973/can-an-imp-which-is-in-another-form-through-shapechanger-be-invisible?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the great link! I've included it as part of the answer

Comment: Still keep the good old "bat hat" (regular familiar form) for fighting warlocks and others under the black light of the *darkness* spell.

Comment: —or become an Eldritch Adept with your own Devil's Sight—